# Is the space C[0,1] connected?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Is the space C[0,1] connected?

For the proof I followed similar steps to [theorem 45.7](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=X_6NMZVMidsC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=Theorem%2045.7&source=bl&ots=CUSS3xiHsV&sig=rUhIelfw3GASPw0iV3-0FHeh1A4&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJzr779cvXAhWDPRoKHSzkAbgQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=Theorem%2045.7&f=false):

Suppose C[0,1] is not connected. Then there exists open nonempty subsets U and V of C[0,1] s.t $C[0,1] = U\cup V$ and $U\cap V = \emptyset$. Let $x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in U$ and $y=(y_1,...,y_n)\in V$. Let
$$f(t) = (tx_1+(1-t)y_1,tx_2+(1-t)y_2,...,tx_n+(1-t)y_n)$$
for $0\leq t \leq1$ . We show that f is continuous from [0,1] into C.

Let $\epsilon >0$. Let $\delta = \epsilon /(\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|)$. If $|t_1 - t_2| < \delta$, then

$d(f(t_1),f(t_2)) < \epsilon$. Then f is continuous.

But I am not sure if the steps are true or this theorem can be applied for C[0,1].

Comment: What does $x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in U$ mean?  Elements of $U$ are functions, not $n$-tuples...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$, $f(x)=tf(x)$, $t\in [0,1]$ defines a path between $f$ and the $0$ function, so $C([0,1])$ is pathe connected hence connected.

Answer (score 5):

For $f,g\in C[0,1]$, for any fixed $t\in[0,1]$, then $tf+(1-t)g\in C[0,1]$, so $C[0,1]$ is convex and hence connected.